# Get file name and creation type from table that based on Google bucket

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I created by Google bigquery UI a table based on Google bucket but now I need to add the file name and creation date columns.

[Google cloud documentation mentioned that tables based on external data sources provide a pseudo column named _FILE_NAME. This column contains the fully qualified path to the file to which the row belongs.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#bq)

So I changed my query to be (for example)

```
SELECT _FILE_NAME AS fn  FROM `my proj.myDataset.mydata`
```

But I got this error

```
Unrecognized name: _FILE_NAME at [4:8]
```

Comment: I just tested locally and confirmed the _FILE_NAME column works for me. Could you double confirm if your table is an "external table"? Could it be that you picked an external data source from GCS but in the `Destination` section you picked Table type to be "Native table" instead of "External table"? (If you did, the data was imported from GCS to BigQuery and there should not be _FILE_NAME column for that table)

Comment: Yes you're right....